# Create filters within groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following result:

```
[4 rows x 10 columns]
          id  ID_ENTIDADE                       ENTIDADE     CHAMADO     ...                 DATA_ALT VALOR_OLD           VALOR_NEW  PRIORIDADE
695  6802505          136 Professional Services > Ser...  2019000518     ...      2019-01-14 15:21:01       NaN             N1 (20)           0
698  6804412          136 Professional Services > Ser...  2019000518     ...      2019-01-14 15:52:46       NaN  Contrato 157 (198)           0
699  6804413          136 Professional Services > Ser...  2019000518     ...      2019-01-14 15:52:46       1.0                   2          14
700  6804415          136 Professional Services > Ser...  2019000518     ...      2019-01-14 15:52:46       3.0                   1           3
701  6804650          136 Professional Services > Ser...  2019000518     ...      2019-01-14 15:53:32       NaN  N1 - Security (25)           0

[5 rows x 10 columns]
          id  ID_ENTIDADE                       ENTIDADE     CHAMADO     ...                 DATA_ALT VALOR_OLD           VALOR_NEW  PRIORIDADE
705  6805135          136 Professional Services > Ser...  2019000519     ...      2019-01-14 16:02:01       NaN             N1 (20)           0
711  6806934          136 Professional Services > Ser...  2019000519     ...      2019-01-14 16:33:41       NaN  N1 - Security (25)           0
712  6806936          136 Professional Services > Ser...  2019000519     ...      2019-01-14 16:33:41       1.0                   2          14
713  6806938          136 Professional Services > Ser...  2019000519     ...      2019-01-14 16:33:41       3.0                   1           3
710  6806932          136 Professional Services > Ser...  2019000519     ...      2019-01-14 16:33:41       NaN  Contrato 157 (198)           0

[5 rows x 10 columns]
          id  ID_ENTIDADE                       ENTIDADE     CHAMADO     ...                 DATA_ALT VALOR_OLD           VALOR_NEW  PRIORIDADE
717  6808869          105 Professional Services > Sup...  2019000523     ...      2019-01-14 17:05:35       NaN  Contrato 135 (136)           0
718  6808870          105 Professional Services > Sup...  2019000523     ...      2019-01-14 17:05:35       NaN        N2 - DC (28)           0
757  6810787          105 Professional Services > Sup...  2019000523     ...      2019-01-14 17:41:31       3.0                   2           3

[3 rows x 10 columns]
          id  ID_ENTIDADE                       ENTIDADE     CHAMADO     ...                 DATA_ALT VALOR_OLD           VALOR_NEW  PRIORIDADE
719  6808990          136 Professional Services > Ser...  2019000524     ...      2019-01-14 17:10:02       NaN             N1 (20)           0
720  6809088          136 Professional Services > Ser...  2019000524     ...      2019-01-14 17:12:59       NaN  Contrato 157 (198)           0
721  6809090          136 Professional Services > Ser...  2019000524     ...      2019-01-14 17:12:59       NaN  N1 - Security (25)           0
722  6809092          136 Professional Services > Ser...  2019000524     ...      2019-01-14 17:12:59       1.0                   2          14
723  6809094          136 Professional Services > Ser...  2019000524     ...      2019-01-14 17:12:59       3.0                   1           3

[5 rows x 10 columns]
```

Which I got with the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("csv3.csv", sep=";", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
df2 = df.sort_values(['CHAMADO', 'id'])


g1 = df2.sort_values(['DATA_ALT'], ascending=True)


ret_group = g1.groupby(['CHAMADO'])

for key, group in ret_group:
    if  group['PRIORIDADE'].any() == True:

        print(group)
```

But I need a filter that checks the first 3 rows of the column "VALOR_NEW" if it has the word "CONTRATO".

I can not create a filter that can do this, every filter I do, it only returns me results where the word "CONTRATO" appears in the first line, as the example below:

```
          id  ID_ENTIDADE                       ENTIDADE     CHAMADO     ...                 DATA_ALT VALOR_OLD           VALOR_NEW  PRIORIDADE
717  6808869          105 Professional Services > Sup...  2019000523     ...      2019-01-14 17:05:35       NaN  Contrato 135 (136)           0
718  6808870          105 Professional Services > Sup...  2019000523     ...      2019-01-14 17:05:35       NaN        N2 - DC (28)           0
757  6810787          105 Professional Services > Sup...  2019000523     ...      2019-01-14 17:41:31       3.0                   2           3

[3 rows x 10 columns]
```

Comment: Can you give us a sample dataframe to test on? there is too much data here, i am confused which one to consider, just a sample data an expected output would help

Comment: The first result can be used as an example. The fact is that I need my filter to bring me results where I see in the first 3 lines if you have the word contract. because there are results where the word contract will not exist

Comment: so you want all groups where the first 3 rows contain th word 'Contrato ' ?

Comment: yes this is the intention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column is a string column just filter values by string `contains`. Assuming your df is `group`. Since you want all the results to show, you could make this not-elegant-solution that makes 3 dataframes:

**first, the ones that contains CONTRATO:**

```
df1 = group.loc[group['VALOR_NEW'].fillna('nada').str.contains('CONTRATO')].head(3)
```

**Then another that doesnt (note the "~" at the start of the .loc, it means opposite:**

```
df2 = group.loc[~group['VALOR_NEW'].fillna('nada').str.contains('CONTRATO')]
```

**Finally you concat both with the ones with CONTRATO first:**

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2])
```

Note that it's case sensitive and that I added a `fillna()` because you can't search if it has nan values.

Edit: added the `.head(3)` at the end to just get the first 3 rows, as you requested.

edit2: edited the original solution

vlwflws

Comment: That brought me just the lines with the word "CONTRATO", I need it to be displayed all, and that filter the word contract in the first 3 lines.

Comment: filter as in show CONTRATO on the first three lines or remove first 3 rows if contains CONTRATO? Am I correct to assume you're also brazilian? If so, could you explain in portuguese aswell?

Comment: Eu preciso que ele filtre e traga todo o resultado, não quero excluir as linhas que possuem a palavra contrato.

Comment: Então mostrar tudo que têm, mas o que tiver CONTRATO nas primeiras linhas? Se tiver mais de 3 resultados com CONTRATO, mostrar apenas 3?

english: He needs all results without excluding ones that has CONTRATO. Also, i asked if it has to just sort the results with CONTRATO first and what should happen if it appears more than 3 times

Comment: his answer helped me with my questioning, but he did another problem, I'm struggling to solve it. If I can not get back to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
my_list = list(df.groupby('CHAMADO').apply(lambda x: x[:3][x[:3]['VALOR_NEW'].str.contains('Contrato',na=False)])['CHAMADO'].values)
#[2019000518, 2019000523, 2019000524]
```

This gives a list of the group which contains the word `Contrato` in the first 3 rows.

```
>>df[df.CHAMADO.isin(my_list)]
```

This will give you the entire dataframe containing those values under `CHAMADO` which has `Contrato` in the first 3 lines.

For storing the values in separate dataframes you can create a dictionary:

```
dfs = ['df_' + str(x) for x in my_list]
dicdf = dict()
i = 0 
while i < len(dfs):
    dicdf[dfs[i]] = df[(df['CHAMADO']== my_list[i])]
    i = i + 1
print(dicdf)
```

You can store via any other methods you like or see in SO.

Comment: Reading the question again after this answer made me understand what was needed. So for each group of "CHAMADO" he needs to check if their first 3 rows contains "Contrato". Good one anky_91

Comment: but I need to separate the items by group, as I do in the ret_group = g1.groupby(['CHAMADO']) the whole dataframe is not for me to analyze the results.

Comment: @AndreyGlauzer so you want a seperate dataframe for every group where the first 3 rows contains the word?

Comment: @AndreyGlauzer : Did you try the solution i gave? this wont return the full dataframe, just those which satisfies your condition.

Comment: Yes I tried, and it returns me only the rows that go into this condition, not the separate dataframe per group

Comment: @AndreyGlauzer you want seperate dataframes for group of 3 or the entire group?

Comment: I need an entire group

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you need to check your grouped dataframes for `'Contrato'` in the `'VALOR_NEW'` column within the first three rows. This check should do it:

```
if (group['VALOR_NEW'].head(3) == 'Contrato').any():
    print(group)
```